# New settings item next to contextual link icon in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-8

I am using drupal 8 for one of my project and i want to add a new item ( gear icon ) right next to contextual link icon which show me a form on popup when admin click on it, Please see the example image
[image]

I am not sure how to make it possible with drupal 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var button = '<button class="fws-block-layout">Block Layout</button>';
            $('.contextual .fws-block-layout').remove();
            $('.contextual button').each(function(){
                var contextual_id = $(this).parent().attr('data-contextual-id');
                if(contextual_id.indexOf("block:block=views_block__fws_view_issues_categories_") >= 0){
                    $(button).insertAfter($(this));
                }
            });
```